# .NET Standard API surface online reference

Tags: .net, xamarin, .net-core

I was just trying to figure out whether the type `System.Windows.Input.ICommand` is part of the new .NET Standard.

I did manage to compile a library using the type when the project target setting was set to `.NETStandard1.0` (it also works when using a broad portable library API surface including .NET Core 1.0).

So, despite the odd namespace suggesting WPF involvement, and despite the namespace not being listed at [this section of a CoreFX document](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/Documentation/architecture/net-platform-standard.md#list-of-net-corefx-apis-and-their-associated-net-platform-standard-version) it appears to be in it.

I wonder if there's also a more accessible reference one can browse to see what API is supported rather than just trying it.

Also, are the API surfaces fixed now, or can this change in the future? In other words, does the test I made give me an authoritative answer at all?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/standard/library Or just search ".NET Standard reference" on your favorite search engine...

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Is this a joke?

Comment: You can try the [Reverse Package Search](https://packagesearch.azurewebsites.net/) tool, which covers the .NET Standard libraries. Not quite as nice as a proper reference though.

Comment: Three guys think this question is not about programming, lol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/api/index has documentation for everything that was in .NET Core 1.0 (not including ASP.Net Core, which is technically a different product). That documentation site covers netstandard1.6 / netcoreapp1.0; but I don't offhand see a way to know when a type/member isn't available in lower versions of netstandard, so as you decrease your netstandard version (which increases the number of compatible platforms) some APIs might disappear (becoming compile errors).

netstandard1.0 through netstandard1.6 are stable, nothing will be deleted from them, and nothing will be added *to* them (new additional packages could be added which have them as the minimum dependency, but that's new API *on* a netstandard version).