# What are the 43 APIs that are in .Net Standard 2.0 but not in .Net Framework 4.6.1?

Tags: .net, .net-core, .net-framework-version, .net-standard

The SO question entitled [.NET Standard API Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40923831/2314532), quoting the discussion in https://github.com/dotnet/standard/issues/133, mentions 43 APIs that will be included in the .Net Standard 2.0 but are not supported by .Net Framework 4.6.1. However, I have not been able to find a list of those 43 APIs anywhere on the Internet. The closest I've come in my search is https://github.com/dotnet/standard/blob/master/docs/versions/netstandard1.5_diff.md and https://github.com/dotnet/standard/blob/master/docs/versions/netstandard1.6_diff.md, which list the APIs introduced in .Net Standard 1.5 and 1.6. At first I thought my search was over, but then I realized:

1. There are way more than 43 APIs in those two lists, and
2. Many of them are supported by .Net Framework 4.6.1 already.

Is there, **anywhere** on the Internet, a list of the 43 **specific** APIs that are included in .Net Standard 2.0 but not included in .Net Framework 4.6.1?

Comment: Ben Adams links in the currently last comment in the GitHub issue to a list of 52 APIs that are not implemented in 4.6.1, isn't this what you are looking for?

Comment: You mean [this list](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/blob/master/netstandard/src/ApiCompatBaseline.net461.txt)? That looks quite useful, thanks! However, as I've been going through http://apisof.net/ to try to answer my own question, I've found some APIs that aren't listed there. (For example, several new APIs in System.Reflection.TypeInfo that aren't in 4.6.1, but don't appear in the list that Ben Adams linked). So I'll continue to write the answer I'm currently writing, and then see what overlap it has with Ben Adams' list.

Answer (score 12):

By using https://apisof.net and checking it against every API listed in https://github.com/dotnet/standard/blob/master/docs/versions/netstandard1.5_diff.md and https://github.com/dotnet/standard/blob/master/docs/versions/netstandard1.6_diff.md, I've managed to put together a list of the APIs present in .Net Standard 1.6 but missing in .Net Framework 4.6.1:

- [`System.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventCounter`](https://apisof.net/catalog/System.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventCounter):

  - `public EventCounter(string name, EventSource eventSource)` (not in .Net Framework)
  - `public void WriteMetric(float value)` (not in .Net Framework)
- [`System.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventSource`](https://apisof.net/catalog/System.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventSource):

  - `public event EventHandler<EventCommandEventArgs> EventCommandExecuted` (in .Net Framework 4.6.2, but not 4.6.1)
- [`System.IO.BufferedStream`](https://apisof.net/catalog/System.IO.BufferedStream):

  - `public int BufferSize { get; }` (not in .Net Framework)
  - `public Stream UnderlyingStream { get; }` (not in .Net Framework)
- [`System.Reflection.TypeInfo`](https://apisof.net/catalog/System.Reflection.TypeInfo): all the following APIs, none of which are in .Net Framework

  ```
  public virtual bool IsCOMObject { get; }
  public override MemberTypes MemberType { get; }
  public virtual StructLayoutAttribute StructLayoutAttribute { get; }
  public ConstructorInfo TypeInitializer { get; }
  public virtual Type UnderlyingSystemType { get; }
  public virtual Type[] FindInterfaces(TypeFilter filter, object filterCriteria);
  public virtual MemberInfo[] FindMembers(MemberTypes memberType, BindingFlags bindingAttr, MemberFilter filter, object filterCriteria);
  public ConstructorInfo GetConstructor(Type[] types);
  public ConstructorInfo[] GetConstructors();
  public virtual ConstructorInfo[] GetConstructors(BindingFlags bindingAttr);
  public virtual MemberInfo[] GetDefaultMembers();
  public virtual string GetEnumName(object value);
  public virtual string[] GetEnumNames();
  public virtual Type GetEnumUnderlyingType();
  public virtual Array GetEnumValues();
  public EventInfo GetEvent(string name);
  public virtual EventInfo GetEvent(string name, BindingFlags bindingAttr);
  public virtual EventInfo[] GetEvents();
  public virtual EventInfo[] GetEvents(BindingFlags bindingAttr);
  public FieldInfo GetField(string name);
  public virtual FieldInfo GetField(string name, BindingFlags bindingAttr);
  public FieldInfo[] GetFields();
  public virtual FieldInfo[] GetFields(BindingFlags bindingAttr);
  public virtual Type[] GetGenericArguments();
  public Type GetInterface(string name);
  public virtual Type GetInterface(string name, bool ignoreCase);
  public virtual Type[] GetInterfaces();
  public MemberInfo[] GetMember(string name);
  public virtual MemberInfo[] GetMember(string name, BindingFlags bindingAttr);
  public virtual MemberInfo[] GetMember(string name, MemberTypes type, BindingFlags bindingAttr);
  public MemberInfo[] GetMembers();
  public virtual MemberInfo[] GetMembers(BindingFlags bindingAttr);
  public MethodInfo GetMethod(string name);
  public MethodInfo GetMethod(string name, BindingFlags bindingAttr);
  public MethodInfo GetMethod(string name, Type[] types);
  public MethodInfo GetMethod(string name, Type[] types, ParameterModifier[] modifiers);
  public MethodInfo[] GetMethods();
  public virtual MethodInfo[] GetMethods(BindingFlags bindingAttr);
  public Type GetNestedType(string name);
  public virtual Type GetNestedType(string name, BindingFlags bindingAttr);
  public Type[] GetNestedTypes();
  public virtual Type[] GetNestedTypes(BindingFlags bindingAttr);
  public PropertyInfo[] GetProperties();
  public virtual PropertyInfo[] GetProperties(BindingFlags bindingAttr);
  public PropertyInfo GetProperty(string name);
  public PropertyInfo GetProperty(string name, BindingFlags bindingAttr);
  public PropertyInfo GetProperty(string name, Type returnType);
  public PropertyInfo GetProperty(string name, Type returnType, Type[] types);
  public PropertyInfo GetProperty(string name, Type returnType, Type[] types, ParameterModifier[] modifiers);
  public PropertyInfo GetProperty(string name, Type[] types);
  public virtual bool IsAssignableFrom(Type c);
  public virtual bool IsEnumDefined(object value);
  public virtual bool IsEquivalentTo(Type other);
  public virtual bool IsInstanceOfType(object o);
  ```
- [`System.AppContext`](https://apisof.net/catalog/System.AppContext):

  - `public static string TargetFrameworkName { get; }` (not in .Net Framework)
  - `public static object GetData(string name)` (not in .Net Framework)
- [`System.Linq.Enumerable`](https://apisof.net/catalog/System.Linq.Enumerable):

  - `public static IEnumerable<TSource> Append<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, TSource element)` (not in .Net Framework)
  - `public static IEnumerable<TSource> Prepend<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, TSource element)` (not in .Net Framework)
- [`System.Security.Cryptography.ECCurve`](https://apisof.net/catalog/System.Security.Cryptography.ECCurve): entire `ECCurve` struct, and everything in it (including the `System.Security.Cryptography.ECCurve.NamedCurves` static class), are not in .Net Framework. In other words, all of the APIs in the following list are new in .Net Core and cannot be found in .Net Framework 4.6.1 (or 4.6.2):

  ```
  public struct ECCurve {
      public enum ECCurveType {
          Characteristic2 = 4,
          Implicit = 0,
          Named = 5,
          PrimeMontgomery = 3,
          PrimeShortWeierstrass = 1,
          PrimeTwistedEdwards = 2,
      }
      public static class NamedCurves {
          public static ECCurve brainpoolP160r1 { get; }
          public static ECCurve brainpoolP160t1 { get; }
          public static ECCurve brainpoolP192r1 { get; }
          public static ECCurve brainpoolP192t1 { get; }
          public static ECCurve brainpoolP224r1 { get; }
          public static ECCurve brainpoolP224t1 { get; }
          public static ECCurve brainpoolP256r1 { get; }
          public static ECCurve brainpoolP256t1 { get; }
          public static ECCurve brainpoolP320r1 { get; }
          public static ECCurve brainpoolP320t1 { get; }
          public static ECCurve brainpoolP384r1 { get; }
          public static ECCurve brainpoolP384t1 { get; }
          public static ECCurve brainpoolP512r1 { get; }
          public static ECCurve brainpoolP512t1 { get; }
          public static ECCurve nistP256 { get; }
          public static ECCurve nistP384 { get; }
          public static ECCurve nistP521 { get; }
      }
      public byte[] A;
      public byte[] B;
      public byte[] Cofactor;
      public ECCurve.ECCurveType CurveType;
      public ECPoint G;
      public Nullable<HashAlgorithmName> Hash;
      public byte[] Order;
      public byte[] Polynomial;
      public byte[] Prime;
      public byte[] Seed;
      public bool IsCharacteristic2 { get; }
      public bool IsExplicit { get; }
      public bool IsNamed { get; }
      public bool IsPrime { get; }
      public Oid Oid { get; }
      public static ECCurve CreateFromFriendlyName(string oidFriendlyName);
      public static ECCurve CreateFromOid(Oid curveOid);
      public static ECCurve CreateFromValue(string oidValue);
      public void Validate();
  }
  ```
- [`System.Security.Cryptography.ECParameters`](https://apisof.net/catalog/System.Security.Cryptography.ECParameters) struct: not in .Net Framework
- [`System.Security.Cryptography.ECPoint`](https://apisof.net/catalog/System.Security.Cryptography.ECPoint) struct: not in .Net Framework
- [`System.Security.Cryptography.ECDsa`](https://apisof.net/catalog/System.Security.Cryptography.ECDsa):

  - `public static ECDsa Create(ECCurve curve)` (not in .Net Framework)
  - `public static ECDsa Create(ECParameters parameters)` (not in .Net Framework)
  - `public virtual ECParameters ExportExplicitParameters(bool includePrivateParameters)` (not in .Net Framework)
  - `public virtual ECParameters ExportParameters(bool includePrivateParameters)` (not in .Net Framework)
  - `public virtual void GenerateKey(ECCurve curve)` (not in .Net Framework)
  - `public virtual void ImportParameters(ECParameters parameters)` (not in .Net Framework)
- [`System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex`](https://apisof.net/catalog/System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex):

  - `protected IDictionary CapNames { get; set; }` (not in .Net Framework)
  - `protected IDictionary Caps { get; set; }` (not in .Net Framework)

That's a lot more than 43 APIs. I haven't yet gone through the .Net Standard 2.0 API list (it's *huge*); once I do, I'll edit this answer to reflect what I find.

Comment: SignedCms and CmsSigner from cryptography pkcs

Comment: The question asked about .NETStandard 2.0, not 1.6.  I saw a note from the devs a while ago to not rely on 1.5 and 1.6 because it isn't going to be compatible with 2.0

Comment: Yes, I know I asked about .Net Standard 2.0. I've only had the time to go through the changes in 1.5 and 1.6 so far; the changes in 2.0 are going to take me FAR longer to work through to answer my own question. Which is why I was hoping someone would be able to point me to an already-existing list.

Answer (score 4):

I posted a [similar question](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/issues/524) in [.Net Standard project](https://github.com/dotnet/standard)

All credit goto   [@benaadams](https://github.com/benaadams)

You can find the missing apis in: [ApiCompatBaseline.net461.txt](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/blob/master/netstandard/src/ApiCompatBaseline.net461.txt)

I checked the file and find 52 entry (more than 43 !).

The 52 missing APIs are:

```
     Member 'System.AppContext.GetData(System.String)' 
     Member 'System.AppContext.TargetFrameworkName.get()' 
     Type 'System.StringNormalizationExtensions' 
     Type 'System.Data.Common.DbColumn' 
     Type 'System.Data.Common.DbDataReaderExtensions' 
     Type 'System.Data.Common.IDbColumnSchemaGenerator' 
     Type 'System.Diagnostics.StackFrameExtensions' 
     Type 'System.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventCounter' 
     Member 'System.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventSource.add_EventCommandExecuted(System.EventHandler<System.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventCommandEventArgs>)' 
     Member 'System.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventSource.remove_EventCommandExecuted(System.EventHandler<System.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventCommandEventArgs>)' 
     Type 'System.Globalization.GlobalizationExtensions' 
     Member 'System.Linq.Enumerable.Append<TSource>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>, TSource)' 
     Member 'System.Linq.Enumerable.Prepend<TSource>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>, TSource)' 
     Member 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<TDelegate>.Compile(System.Boolean)' 
     Member 'System.Linq.Expressions.LambdaExpression.Compile(System.Boolean)' 
     Member 'System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.CheckCertificateRevocationList.get()' 
     Member 'System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.CheckCertificateRevocationList.set(System.Boolean)' 
     Member 'System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.ClientCertificates.get()' 
     Member 'System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.DefaultProxyCredentials.get()' 
     Member 'System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.DefaultProxyCredentials.set(System.Net.ICredentials)' 
     Member 'System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.MaxConnectionsPerServer.get()' 
     Member 'System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.MaxConnectionsPerServer.set(System.Int32)' 
     Member 'System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.MaxResponseHeadersLength.get()' 
     Member 'System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.MaxResponseHeadersLength.set(System.Int32)' 
     Member 'System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.Properties.get()' 
     Member 'System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback.get()' 
     Member 'System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback.set(System.Func<System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Chain, System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors, System.Boolean>)' 
     Member 'System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.SslProtocols.get()' 
     Member 'System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.SslProtocols.set(System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols)' 
     Type 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketReceiveFromResult' 
     Type 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketReceiveMessageFromResult' 
     Type 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketTaskExtensions' 
     Type 'System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializerExtensions' 
     Type 'System.Runtime.Serialization.ISerializationSurrogateProvider' 
     Type 'System.Security.SecureStringMarshal' 
     Type 'System.Security.Cryptography.ECCurve' 
     Member 'System.Security.Cryptography.ECDsa.Create(System.Security.Cryptography.ECCurve)' 
     Member 'System.Security.Cryptography.ECDsa.Create(System.Security.Cryptography.ECParameters)' 
     Member 'System.Security.Cryptography.ECDsa.ExportExplicitParameters(System.Boolean)' 
     Member 'System.Security.Cryptography.ECDsa.ExportParameters(System.Boolean)' 
     Member 'System.Security.Cryptography.ECDsa.GenerateKey(System.Security.Cryptography.ECCurve)' 
     Member 'System.Security.Cryptography.ECDsa.ImportParameters(System.Security.Cryptography.ECParameters)' 
     Type 'System.Security.Cryptography.ECParameters' 
     Type 'System.Security.Cryptography.ECPoint' 
     Type 'System.Security.Cryptography.IncrementalHash' 
     Member 'System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.CapNames.get()' 
     Member 'System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.CapNames.set(System.Collections.IDictionary)' 
     Member 'System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Caps.get()' 
     Member 'System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Caps.set(System.Collections.IDictionary)' 
     Type 'System.Threading.PreAllocatedOverlapped' 
     Type 'System.Threading.ThreadPoolBoundHandle' 
     Type 'System.Xml.XPath.XDocumentExtensions'
```

I checked most of these API  and  found  that they  are not available in net461, but available in netstandard2

---

**Update Nov, 2017:**

With the final release of [.NET Framework 4.7.1](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/10/17/announcing-the-net-framework-4-7-1/), all missing APIs in 4.6.1 are implemented.

[List of implemented API](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/blob/master/netstandard/src/ApiCompatBaseline.net461.txt)

Now .Net Standard 2.0 are built right into the .NET Framework 4.7.1 itself without the need to install .Net Standard 2.0 supported binaries.